# The qml interface cannot be displayed normally

Tags: qml, q

The qt qml program compiled on my personal computer can run on some win10 pro computers, but some computers cannot display the screen normally. Then I tried to configure the same compilation environment for compilation on these computers that could not be displayed normally, but the qml interface still could not be displayed normally. While the qml interface cannot be displayed, a file writing function based on qfile cannot be used normally. When the qml interface is displayed normally, this function can be used normally. My compilation environment is qt5.9.9, msvc2013 32bit and win10 pro.

First of all, I guessed that the qml environment was not configured, so I planned to compile it directly on the computer that did not display the screen, but it still could not display normally.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Qt, typically uses the OpenGL backend. You can diagnose your Windows environment by running qtdiag.exe to see what are the differences between the Windows machines that do work versus the Windows machines that do not.

Another thing you can do is ensure that the graphics card, and/or graphics drivers are kept up to date. i.e. consider changing the graphics card and/or updating the graphics driver.

Qt also supports other rendering engines other than OpenGL. You can swap out OpenGL by either using the `-opengl` command line argument, or, set the `QT_OPENGL` environment variable.

| QT_OPENGL | Description |
| --- | --- |
| desktop | Use OpenGL drovers from your hardware vendor |
| angle | Use OpenGL ES 2.0 API on top of DirectX 11 or 9 |
| software | Use OpenGL software-only implementation |

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-index.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html